# Unity VR can't see textures on build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

we are making an VR experience and we have some textures that are displaying like this: [image](The supervisor texture floating there has the same import settings, but it is displayed correctly)

This are the import setting of the image:
[image]

When we put some textures on separeate scenes this stops happening, but we need them all in a single scene. We tried to load them from Resources when needed, still happening.

(Textures are stereoscopic)

Any suggestion of what can we do to fix it?

Update: Memmory lectures.

[image]
[image]
(Profiler tells me that i'm using 2.9Gb of the 4.6Gb used in total)

Comment: Is this a mobile application? Have you profiled the memory? This looks to me like out of memory error?

Comment: Make texture size <= 2048

Comment: -No, it is a PC app. Yes i've profiled it and i dont see a memory overflow.

Comment: -Texture must be 8k, if not, they can't be readen.

Comment: `When we put some textures on separeate scenes this stops happening,` sounds like memory to me

Comment: Yes, we thought that was something with memmory but we are confused because the lectures of the memory are fine or at least we think that are fine. Then, unity has some memory usage cap? How can I solve this if it is a memory issue? I updated the post with profiler lectures